# Anchor links inside div aren't accessible by tab key anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript, accessibility

I'm currently delving on an A11y issue the project I'm working on has.

We have an `upvotes` div that hides when the user hovers over it (with the mouse) or focus on it (with the `tab` key) **if** said user isn't logged in.

When this happens, a `signup/signin` div appears with 2 anchor links prompting the user to sign up or log in.

This is the code we originally had (on CoffeeScript):

```
hoverize: (votes) ->
  $(document).on {
    'mouseenter focus': ->
      $("div.participation-not-allowed", this).show()
      $("div.participation-allowed", this).hide()
    mouseleave: ->
      $("div.participation-not-allowed", this).hide()
      $("div.participation-allowed", this).show()
  }, votes
```

The problem with this code was that, if the user moved around the website with the `tab` key, the `signup/signin` div would stayed focused and wouldn't hide until the user hovered over it with the mouse.

We fixed this adding [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) to the `mouseleave` function, which give us the following code:

```
hoverize: (votes) ->
  $(document).on {
    "mouseenter focus": ->
      $("div.participation-not-allowed", this).show()
    "mouseleave blur": ->
      $("div.participation-not-allowed", this).hide()
  }, votes
```

But now, the anchor links inside the `signup/signin` div aren't accessible with the `tab` key anymore.

Here's an image which depicts the current behaviour

[image: current behavior].

And here's another one which depicts the desired implementation

[image: desired implementation].